Why does Visual Studio's popup sometimes display non-nullable reference types as nullable?
I've noticed an oddity in the way Visual Studio's popup (when you hover over a variable) displays non-nullable reference types, for example:

clipData.GetFormats() returns a string[] - a non-nullable array of non-nullable strings.  Yet when I hover over formats, it says that it's a nullable (having a question mark after it), but then adds that it's not null below.  Why not just display the type as the non-nullable string[]?  Similarly, if I hover over format it gives the type as string? but adds that it is "not null here"; why not give its type as the non-nullable string?
In case anyone answers "because reference types are always nullable internally", Visual Studio does not do this if I explicitly declare a non-nullable string; in that case, the popup gives the type as a non-nullable type:


This is a constant source of confusion, even though it was done for very good reasons, and makes a lot of sense once you understand how the flow state work with NRTs. Arguably the most confusing thing is the ? in the intellisense pop-up. I've linked your question to a bunch of others which have answers which hopefully make the situation clearer
